# Possible to have two post methods in the same app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless

In my project i have the following function:

```
createSite:
    handler: CreateSite.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: sites
          method: post
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam
```

but is it possible to have another post function directed at the same dynamodb but with different attributes etc. Because if I make another post method how do i specify which one to call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have another post method directed at the same backend system with different attributes but you need to map that post method with a different http path. It will look something like this:

```
createSite:
    handler: CreateSite.main
    events:
      - http:
          path: sites_v2
          method: post
          cors: true
          authorizer: aws_iam
```

Comment: That's actually what I'm trying to do now, I specified the attributes in the function code which i should have done, i should call it as one object so it can be more dynamic. Thanks!